# Ubuntu 19.04 - Partition issue

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have used my laptop dual booting both Windows 10 and Ubuntu for a while now, and its been working great. However, after becoming more accustomed to Ubuntu ive decided to move some of my projects over there and therefore require more space.

What i Did:

1: Used Gparted in Ubuntu to reduce the size of my Windows partition, creating 60GB of unallocated space.

2: Tried to extend my Ubuntu partition with this space using Gparted. (Realising after i tried that i cannot do this while booted)

3: Went to Windows and used DiskGenious trying to allocate the 60GB to my Ubuntu partition.

The problem is that neither works, and i get an similar error while trying to do something with the 60GB that i freed from the Windows partition. I also tried to allocate the 60GB back to windows, but i got the same error.

Hope someone can guide me in the right direction so that i can use the 60GB for my Ubuntu.

Error log: https://textuploader.com/1144v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to expand your Ubuntu partition if you boot from an Ubuntu install disk, go into the try me session and use gparted from there.